# Running Program

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans-7

I'm currently using NetBeans IDE 7.4.
When i (Clean and Build) my programs, they don't work unless there is a GUI. For example i have made 2 programs, a calculator and a click counter that had GUI and worked from the .java file. The simple "Hello World" program without a GUI and a number guessing game i made without GUI do not work from the .java file. The programs work completely fine in the IDE but after i (clean and build) the .java file of the projects do not even open. Does every program have to have a GUI? I thought programs like "Hello World" would be ran from the cmd by default. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What exactly are you doing to start these programs? And what exactly do you get as a result?

Comment: To start the programs i am going to my project directory, going into the project folder, then the dist folder, and double clicking on executable jar file. My result looks as if it is loading for a second, and then nothing. For the projects with GUI however the file opens and operates perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you double-click a jar file, the command that is actually run (which is associated with jar files) is `javaw`. `javaw` runs a Java program without opening a command line window. Double-clicking a jar file is indeed intended to run a GUI app.

If your program is a command line program, you should open a command line window, go to your dist folder, and execute

```
java -jar yourJarFile.jar
```

If you really want to have a double-clickable file that starts your command-line application, then provide a script (.sh/.bat) that runs the above command.

Answer (score 0):

> Does every program have to have a GUI?

No it doesn't.  Apps. that have no GUI include:

- Command line apps. and apps. intended to run on headless environments.
- JEE apps. (though servlets and JSP and such do effectively create an HTML based GUI).

> The programs work completely fine in the IDE but after i (clean and build) the .java file of the projects do not even open.

To get some output, run it from the command line using something like:

```
>java -jar the.jar
```

See the [`java` command](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) & the `jar` option for more info.